# Magnolia Vaadin Field

Tags: java, content-management-system, vaadin, vaadin7, magnolia

Im' trying to add a [color picker](https://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/data-input/other/color-picker) to show at my dialog when adding a component.
I did follow this documentation ([Custom fields](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Custom+fields#Customfields-Usingafieldinaform)) and reading some information online I end up with this implementation:

**ColorPickerDefinition**

```
package com.acme.templates.components.field.definition;

import info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.ConfiguredFieldDefinition;

public class ColorPickerDefinition extends ConfiguredFieldDefinition{
    private String colorPicker;

    public String getColorPicker() {
        return colorPicker;
    }

    public void setColorPicker(String colorPicker) {
        this.colorPicker = colorPicker;
    }
}
```

**ColorPickerFactory**

```
package com.acme.templates.components.field.factory;
import com.vaadin.shared.ui.colorpicker.Color;
import com.vaadin.ui.AbstractColorPicker;
import com.vaadin.ui.ColorPicker;
import com.vaadin.ui.ColorPickerArea;
import com.vaadin.ui.Notification;
import com.vaadin.ui.components.colorpicker.ColorChangeEvent;
import com.vaadin.ui.components.colorpicker.ColorChangeListener;


public class ColorPickerFactory extends AbstractColorPicker {
    protected AbstractColorPicker sample;

    public ColorPickerFactory() {
        super();
    }


    public ColorPickerFactory(String popupCaption) {
        super(popupCaption);
    }

    public ColorPickerFactory(String popupCaption, Color initialColor) {
        super(popupCaption, initialColor);
        setDefaultCaptionEnabled(true);
    }

    protected AbstractColorPicker createFieldComponent() {
        sample = new ColorPicker();
        sample.setSwatchesVisibility(false);
        sample.setHistoryVisibility(false);
        sample.setTextfieldVisibility(false);
        sample.setHSVVisibility(false);

        sample.addColorChangeListener(new ColorChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void colorChanged(final ColorChangeEvent event) {
                Notification.show(
                        "Color changed: " + event.getColor().getCSS(),
                        Notification.Type.TRAY_NOTIFICATION);
            }
        });

        return sample;
    }

    @Override
    protected void setDefaultStyles() {
        setPrimaryStyleName(STYLENAME_BUTTON);
        addStyleName(STYLENAME_DEFAULT);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeClientResponse(boolean initial) {
        super.beforeClientResponse(initial);

        if (isDefaultCaptionEnabled()
                && ((getState().caption == null || ""
                .equals(getState().caption)))
                && "".equals(getState().width)) {
            getState().width = "100px";
        }
    }
}
```

**My component**

```
package com.acme.templates.components;

import com.acme.templates.components.field.definition.ColorPickerDefinition;
import info.magnolia.dam.app.ui.config.DamConfig;
import info.magnolia.module.blossom.annotation.TabFactory;
import info.magnolia.module.blossom.annotation.Template;
import info.magnolia.module.blossom.annotation.TemplateDescription;
import info.magnolia.ui.form.config.TabBuilder;
import info.magnolia.ui.framework.config.UiConfig;
import javax.jcr.RepositoryException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@Template(id = "acmemodule:components/example", title = "Example")
@TemplateDescription(" ")
public class Example {

    @RequestMapping("/example")
    public String render() throws RepositoryException {
        return "components/example.ftl";

    }

    @TabFactory("LineExample")

    public void addDialog(UiConfig cfg, TabBuilder tab, DamConfig dam) {

        ColorPickerDefinition cpd = new ColorPickerDefinition();
                cpd.setColorPicker("cp");
                cpd.setName("Name");
                cpd.setLabel("Label");
        tab.fields(

        ).definition().addField(cpd);
    }

}
```

Now, when I try to add a new component (with this field) I can't see anything in the dialog area.

Comment: what version of vaadin are you using?

Comment: Vaadin framework 7

Comment: How do you register this field in the registry? Can you post configuration as well? Also what might be an issue is that none of your `<ctors>` in the factory are annotated with `@Inject`. One of them should have annotation to tell guice what to use. Pbly irrelevant to the issue, but in the future you might want to extend `info.magnolia.ui.form.field.factory.AbstractFieldFactory<XXXFieldDefinition, String>` but perhaps your `AbstractColorPicker` does.

Comment: where does this code go?